# Access elements from listmodel

Tags: android, listview, qml

I am new to Qml programming language and I am facing this error. I got a working code from the internet and I tried modifying it a little bit but I am not able to understand what is happening.

So this is the Listview that I am using I have two components named Device with ip cpdevice and Deviceinfo with id cpdeviceinfo.
The first thing that I dont understand is on the step

model:cpdevice.devicelist what is exactly happening over here?
Does this mean that devicelist that I am accessing is a listmodel??
if yes can someone explain me how to access elements from listmodel.
Apart from using get function?

`ListView{
        id:mainview
        x: 8
        y: 148
        width:parent.width
        height: parent.height/4
        model:cpdevice.devicesList
        delegate:
            Rectangle{
            height:250
            width:parent.width/2
            color: "transparent"
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            border.width: 2
            border.color: "#aa0000"
            radius: 2
            Rectangle {
                id: box
                anchors.fill:parent
                color:"transparent"
                Component.onCompleted: {
                    console.log("Inside List view");
                }`

```
            Text {
                id: deviceName
                font.pointSize: 20
                color: "#363636"
                horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
                elide: Text.ElideMiddle
                width: implicitWidth
                wrapMode: Text.Wrap
                text: modelData.deviceName
                anchors.top: parent.top
                anchors.topMargin: 15
                anchors.left: parent.left
                anchors.leftMargin: 22

                Component.onCompleted: {
                    console.log("In Device Name")
                    devname=cpdevice.devicesList.deviceName
                    console.log(devname)
                }
            }
            Text {
                id: deviceAddress
                text: modelData.deviceAddress
                font.pointSize: deviceName.font.pointSize
                color: "#363636"
                horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
                elide: Text.ElideMiddle
                width: implicitWidth
                wrapMode: Text.Wrap
                anchors.top:deviceName.bottom
                anchors.topMargin: 15
                anchors.left: parent.left
                anchors.leftMargin: 22

                Component.onCompleted: {
                    console.log("In device Address")
                    console.log(modelData.deviceAddress)
                    devadd=modelData.deviceAddress;
                }

            }
        }
    }

}`
```

Comment: You cannot tell if 'cpdevice.devicesList' is a ListModel, because the definition is not in your example. On a ListView you are using the model parameter can be a QML-Model (e,g. ListModel) or a Vector / List of QObjects, or even a int (as count). Please provide more Information.

Comment: I am sorry for the delay.... I am unable to format my code here or edit it.. cpdevice.devicelist is a getting the element out of Qlist and converting it in to a Qvariant... I was able to access the elements by using it as ...cpdevice.devicelist[0].devicename